# sencha extjs4.1 ext.tab.panel activetab

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

How can I use the setactivetab for grid within tab.panel?
I need my onload button/grid to stay in the tab panel that it actives from.
When I click on the button from the second tab I want the second tab to set. Instead it returns to the first tab. Below is my bare bones code, as I stripped out my attempt to use the setactivetab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//begin menu bar
Ext.define('MainNavBar.view.ui.MainNavPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    height: 170,
    width: 1000,
    activeTab: 0,
    initComponent: function() {    
        var me = this;
        me.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 145,
                width: 684,
                title: 'Bus Data',
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        height: 145,
                        width: 938,
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [

                            {
                                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                                height: 140,
                                title: 'Bid',
                                columns: 2,
                                layout: {
                                    columns: 2,
                                    type: 'table'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Bid Doc',
                                        handler: function(){window.location = '/biddoc/';}                                        
                                    },
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 115,
                title: 'Reporting',
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        height: 140,
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                                height: 140,
                                title: 'Sales Data',
                                columns: 2,
                                layout: {
                                    columns: 2,
                                    type: 'table'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Batch',
                                        handler: function(){window.location = '/salesdatabatch/';}  
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },

        ];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});       
Ext.define('MainNavBar.view.MainNavPanel', {
    extend: 'MainNavBar.view.ui.MainNavPanel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});
Ext.application({
    name: 'MainNavBar',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.QuickTips.init();

        var cmp1 = Ext.create('MainNavBar.view.MainNavPanel', {
            renderTo: menu
        });
        cmp1.show();
    }
});
//end menu bar

        </script>
```

Comment: Are you going to do this with code: handler: function(){window.location = '/biddoc/';}   ?

Comment: Try to add xtype for your `MainNavBar.view.ui.MainNavPanel` xtype: `mainNavPanel`.
With handler function do this: **this.up('mainNavPanel).setActiveTab(0 or 1);** for appropriate index

Comment: ok, so I added xtype: mainNavPanel to MainNavBar.view.ui.MainNavPanel on line 3 like this: Ext.define('MainNavBar.view.ui.MainNavPanel', {
    xtype: mainNavPanel,     Now the handler, how do i add this.up('mainNavPanel).setActiveTab(0 or 1); to the  handler: function(){window.location = '/biddoc/';} ?

Comment: some good news. I was able to use your suggestion to trigger the Reporting tab from the 'biddoc' button. but the page goes back to tab 0 after a flash of the Reporting Tab (second tab). The code I use for the trigger is this:         handler: function(){window.location = '/biddoc/';this.up('mainNavPanel').setActiveTab(1);}

Comment: so the setActiveTab(1) seems to work for a second then goes back to the default tab(0). Any ideas?

Comment: Its because you are redirecting to page and default index is propagated. You need to remove window.location for something more desired solution.

Comment: You should not navigate to another url for changing the tabs. There is an architectural problem with your application. With ExtJs you would normally stay always on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Lets compile everything that we discussed here and make correct answer.

@Lorenz Meyer has good point there. You have architecture problem and you can solve this for example by `Ext.Ajax.request({/** code here **/});`. So there is no redirecting.
If you need good example how to do this, please refer to this: [Extjs - Servlets](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/03/extjs-ajax-json-request-response.html)

But you did not ask for architecture problem so this is my answer.

So after a little thinking i just made some corrects to your code. Please take a look and if its something that you like it just mark as answered:

```
Ext.define('MainNavBar.view.ui.MainNavPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    height: 170,
    width: 1000,
    activeTab: 0,
    initComponent: function() {    
        var me = this;
        me.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 145,
                width: 684,
                title: 'Bus Data',
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        height: 145,
                        width: 938,
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [

                            {
                                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                                height: 140,
                                title: 'Bid',
                                columns: 2,
                                layout: {
                                    columns: 2,
                                    type: 'table'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Bid Doc',
                                        handler: function(){window.location = '/biddoc/';}                                        
                                    },
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                height: 115,
                title: 'Reporting',
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        height: 140,
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                                height: 140,
                                title: 'Sales Data',
                                columns: 2,
                                layout: {
                                    columns: 2,
                                    type: 'table'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Batch',
                                        handler: function(){window.location = '/salesdatabatch/';}  
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(component, eOpts) {
                var urlInfo = document.location.href;
                if(urlInfo.contains('salesdatabatch')){
                    component.setActiveTab(1);
                }
                if(urlInfo.contains('biddoc')){
                    component.setActiveTab(0);
                }
            }
        },
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```